# Date Picker image is missing in my implementation? using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am implementing a date picker. But a default image is missing from the left side. I don't know why it is not shown in the browser. When I saw demo it is displayed well.
I used this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jQuery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jQuery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>

<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true,"zindex":1200}'/>
```

But image is not displayed.

Here is my code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip

I this is a CSS issue. (CSS conflicts?)

Comment: Do not attach zip files if you want people to answer you question. Make the post longer write code snippets. Try to minimize your problem and keep only the essencial code (HTML, CSS *AND* JS)

Comment: actually when i right code on fiddle it is working fine ..!!But when i integrate that code in my code it is not displaying an icon

Comment: post the fiddle in your question and tell people what is different form what you see in your code.

Comment: actually when i check on fiddle it is working fine .only problem is on integration my code is working only problem of icon which is not display

Comment: only run index.html .problem is date box icon is not display .I this there is conflict of css that why i am asking this

Comment: Here is my working fiddle where the icon is display .It is not display on my project http://jsfiddle.net/3yG9E/2/

Comment: i think there is problem of conflict css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date picker image is given by the class `ui-icon-datebox`. This one is in your HTML.

The `ui-icon-datebox` CSS class is defined in:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This file is also there in `<zip>/css/jqm-datebox.min.css`. This is also OK.

This class says for `.ui-icon-datebox`:

```
background-image: url('image/datebox.png')!important;
background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
background-position: 99% 8px!important;
```

But if you go now to: `` `<zip>/css/image `` you find no file named: `datebox.png`. So this is the problem.

NOTE: As a general advice, do not move files around when you are working with external CSS/JS libraries. Keep the `css`, `js`, `img` for your own code. Just dump the external libraries in a directory called `external` (or smth. similar) and leave their structure as you downloaded them. This can help you avoid such problems because many libraries define their own directory structure and you don't want to "disturb" the internal image/CSS file references.

Comment: THANKS..that is awesome answer ...Can you please help me one more issue to search a text from div ..

Comment: just post the question on SO and you will for sure find plenty of answers. Just exercise you `asking` skills.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't download your code.

Have you checked if maybe the image files need to be referenced differently? The JS files might be using relative references, you could try changing them so that they **reference file paths from the root.**

Example, changing "img/calendar.gif" to "/lib/img/calendar.gif" within the JS files (**or CSS files** if any are used).

Comment: But on fiddle it is working I only do same thing import js and css file

Comment: Date picker is display but icon not,,